# A simple 'treebus'

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

This is a simple rebus, just the one picture:

[image: black tree with white N, with a restricted circle overlayed]

<sub>shiloutette from http://getdrawings.com/live-oak-tree-silhouette#live-oak-tree-silhouette-12.jpg</sub>

Comment: I feel like you missed an opportunity to name this a "treebus"

Comment: @Reibello I suggested this as an edit ~ and I believe it got accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This says-

> No Entry (No N tree)

Comment: Spot on! You are correct.

Comment: thanks, you can accept an answer by clicking on the green tick beside it. :)

Comment: Or I could wait, and see if the question gets more views

Comment: okay, no worries ..